# Console Application cannot start after manifest has been added

Tags: c#, console-application, manifest

I have simple console application that will do some changes in the registry, so I need to run its as Admin. For this purpose I add app.manifest with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="RegisterEditor.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel evel="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

After, I start to get error:

```
Cannot start application because of wrong configuration. Check manifest file for errors.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please include the actual, full error you receive and show your research. It looks like you omitted the "L" of "level" though.

Comment: Is the assembly identity correct? RegisterEditor.app doesn't look like the name of the output assembly. And you are missing the letter 'l', it should be 'level' and not 'evel'

Comment: Manifest error details are always logged in the Windows application log.  Using the sxstrace.exe utility would be another way.  But pretty obvious that this manifest is evel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a type in your manifest. The attribute name should be `level` and not 'evel':

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level=”requireAdministrator”/>
```